# dropdown is not working, only inserting 0

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there i have an issue with inserting code from the dropdown menu. The rest of the values are inserting perfectly fine, but the one from the dropdown is just inserting 0.

HTML:

```
 <form action="send_registration.php" method="post">

    <p>

        <label for="username">Username:</label>

        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="password">password:</label>

        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>

        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

    </p>

  <p>


<label for="countryID">Country:</label>
<select>
<option name="countryID" id="countryID" value="countryID" >
    <option value="1">"Andorra" </option>
    <option value="2">"United Arab Emirates" </option>
    <option value="3">"wont bore with the rest" </option>
</option>

</select>

    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include('connection.php');
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL

server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */





// Check connection

if($conn === false){

    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

}



// Escape user inputs for security

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['username']);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['password']);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']);
$countryID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['countryID']);

 $encrypt_password = md5($password);

// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, countryID) VALUES ('$username', '$encrypt_password', '$email',  '$countryID')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

    header("Location: login.php");

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);

}



// close connection

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: `md5()`is obsolete for hashing passwords and should *not be used*. PHP provides [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: `<option>` does not bear the name attribute, `<select>` does.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak hash like MD5**.

Comment: As a note, it's usually better to use two-letter [ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) codes instead of arbitrary numbers like this. For example: USA -> 'US', France -> 'FR' and so on.

Comment: Lovely thank you very much for your answers. I need to brush up quite a lot on the php, quite new to it, will try some of these things when i know a bit more about it, it is now inserting into the DB correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have the name of the dropdown on an option tag, it should be on the select tag like so.

```
<select name="countryID" id="countryID">
  <option value="1">"Andorra" </option>
  <option value="2">"United Arab Emirates" </option>
  <option value="3">"wont bore with the rest" </option>
</select>
```